# Can a person be sued for writing a script to scrape websites?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I recently made a video on YouTube that was designed to help people create a bot that would automatically refresh a website every 45 seconds to check if a certain product was available on Newegg. Once it found the product, it would use Selenium Webdriver to go through the checkout process automatically.

I gave everyone a free copy of my script to use, and everything was going great until the company that owned the website saw the video and filed a copyright claim on it. I don't think I did anything wrong, but I wanted to get a legal opinion on the situation. Is it possible that they could sue me?

I don't think I violated the copyright of their website since I used Python to create the program and it was my own original work. The only thing I can think of that could be a copyright issue is that I recorded a live video of the bot going through the automated checkout process, or I used specific XPATH text from their website for the bot to navigate.

Could you let me know what you think? I'd like to counter their claim, but I'm scared of getting sued.

Answer (score -6):

### Did you show images of their website?

If you did, this is a clear copyright violation and they will certainly win any copyright claim they have launched against you.

Comment: Please, remember that the goal is legal education rather than legal advice (even if it's legal advice which doesn't rise up to the level of representation).  Please, state application concepts on which you rely to arrive at your answer with possible links to where the OP can learn more.

Comment: "Clear copyright violation" may not be as clear as it seems, in the UK at least. (CDPA sec 30 and 31)

Comment: How is this different than a grocery store showing images of branded products they sell in their advertising material?